# Using vm (view model) variable notation in Controllers - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing Angular JS tutorials. I've no clue why this notation have been used. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Code in the `controller.js` file:

```
var vm = this;

vm.openSideBar = openSideBar; // Did not understand this line

function openSideBar() {
    $mdSidenav('left').open();
};
```

Comment: Well, it adds a property named openSideBar to vm, and the value of this property is the function openSideBar(), defined right after. And vm is a variable referring to `this`. It's a longer way of writing `this.openSideBar = function() { $mdSidenav('left').open(); };`.

Comment: Also vm = this is used to workaround scope issues. I advise you to go through this style guide as it's currently best one there is for Angular 1.x, you will never have to do var vm = this; if you use it: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

The code that you post is purely stylistic and takes advantage of [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) to enable the bindable functions to be displayed at the top of the file, and the details (implementations) for those to be kept separate and specified further down the file.

**Benefits**

The benefits of this approach are more apparent as the number of bindable functions in the controller increases:

- **Easier to read (what's important)**. Since the purpose of the controller is to support the view and supply it with bindings, the *what* is more important than the *how* i.e. What the view can bind to is more important than how the controller goes about it's work. You can see immediately on opening the file what the controller can do for the view.
- **Easier to find (the details)**. Having the bindable functions at the top of the file acts as like a contents page for the file. Most IDE's will highlight matching variables if you place the cursor over them and that helps find the implementation details further down the file.
- **Encourages single responsibility**. Your controller should be supplying bindings for a view, and only one view. You can see at the top of your file if you start to build up lots of unrelated bindable functions that serve different purposes that you might be trying to do too much in one controller.
- **Encourages named functions**. This is particularly useful for debugging as it means that you will have less anonymous functions in your application, which in turn makes reading call stacks in developer tools easier.

**Further Reading**

Check out John Papa's [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) which has been approved by the Angular team. You can read all about the thought behind this approach under the heading [Bindable Members Up Top](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#bindable-members-up-top) in the Controllers section (although it can be applied to factories/services/directives also).

Answer (score 0):

openSideBar was add to view model. it was aviable to run this func from view like `<someElement ng-click="$ctrl.openSideBar()"></someElement>`

Answer (score 0):

The VM model or way of doing is quite old... before ES6 came along.

Nowadays, I would suggest you learn ES6, take a look at Todd Motto's AngularJS style guide https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide.

But here an answer to your question:

```
// OLD WAY
function MyAppController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

    vm.getBlue() {
        return vm.colors[1];
    }

    vm.handleClickEvent(e) {
        // this keyword is now the dom element, not your controller
        // this is why the VM pattern came to life.

        this.classList.add(vm.getBlue());
    }
}

// NEW WAY
class MyAppController {
    $onInit() {
        this.colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
    }

    getBlue() {
        return this.colors[1];
    }

    handleClickEvent(e) {
        // Here this keyword is still your controller, NOT the dom
        // element (provided you used angular's ng-click directive
        const elem = e.target;
        elem.classList.add(this.getBlue);
    }
}
```

With ES6, it is rare that you have to same a reference to `this` since you can use arrow functions. You should also get familiar with `bind()`, `call()`, and `apply()` methods to control which context you want to apply to functions.